# Calling web service out of order

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services

I have java script that looks like

```
var message2 = "";
Commission.prototype.communityChanged = function() {
    BT.WebServices.InternalServices.Commission_CheckUnprocessed(function (data) {message2 = data; }, this.callFailed);

    if (message2 == "0") {
        alert("0");
    }
}
```

That calls my server side web service. Pretty straightforward.

Web service code looks like

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string Commission_CheckUnprocessed() {
    return "0";
}
```

The issue is the javascript code finishes, then the web service is called. Out of order. So my message2 is never assigned the correct value.

What do I need to add to make it operate in the correct order?

Comment: write your code you want to execute after web service returned in `function (data) {/* Your Code */}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `function(data)` is a callback function it means that it will be executed when the request is completed. If you have .NET background you can think of this like an event or delegate. This means that the `function(data)` was not meant to be executed sequentially.

I recommend you this article to understand what is happening

http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, inside **BT.WebServices.InternalServices.Commission_CheckUnprocessed** there is a call to your service and this method takes 2 params: success-callback and fail-callback.

So if the call to service inside **Commission_CheckUnprocessed** is [synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) then the code below it will wait till it ends. In that case your code is correct but not user-friendly as you block the UI during the request-time.

If the call to service is asynchronous then you should do any actions inside callbacks, so your code should be like:

```
Commission.prototype.communityChanged = function() {
    BT.WebServices.InternalServices.Commission_CheckUnprocessed(function (data) {
        if (data === "0") {
            alert("0");
        }
    }, this.callFailed);
}
```

Read more about why you should choose an async way [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363576/What-is-the-Asynchronous-Web-and-How-is-it-Revolutionary) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)